# Grails Rebuilds whole project

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a project that has been upgraded recently from grails 1.3.7 to grails 2.5.

I was using Java 6 and I am now using Java 7.

On the same machine, with both projects I notice a great delay in the compilation of my grails 2.5 project.

Specifically, if I am in a unit test class and add just one live (it can even be an empty space), save the file and then re-run my test, it will recompile everything.

This process normally takes around 30 seconds where before it would only take 3 or 4.

This is what I noticed on the logs however I haven't found any useful information online which could help my scenario.

I have also seen on online forums that people mention some grails plugin force the project to be rebuilt entirely?

```
2015-09-28 13:20:24,202 [ 485962]   INFO - cremental.groovy.GroovyBuilder - Order chunk rebuild
2015-09-28 13:20:24,202 [ 485962]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Builder Groovy stub generator requested rebuild of module chunk newModule
2015-09-28 13:20:39,160 [ 500920]   INFO - brains.jps.incremental.Builder - Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
2015-09-28 13:20:39,754 [ 501514]   INFO - rains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession - Build duration: 'Groovy compiler' builder took 30832 ms, 360 sources processed
2015-09-28 13:20:39,754 [ 501514]   INFO - rains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession - Build duration: 'Groovy stub generator' builder took 18373 ms, 0 sources processed
2015-09-28 13:20:39,755 [ 501515]   INFO - rains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession - Build duration: 'NotNull instrumentation' builder took 2121 ms, 0 sources processed
2015-09-28 13:20:39,755 [ 501515]   INFO - rains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession - Build duration: 'java' builder took 3684 ms, 1 sources processed
2015-09-28 13:20:39,755 [ 501515]   INFO - rains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession - Build duration: 'IntelliLang Pattern Validator' builder took 386 ms, 0 sources processed
```

Answer (score 0):

After liaising with JetBrains, this issue will be fixed in IntelliJ 15 as mentioned here in this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142891

If you have a Grails v2+ project and use IntelliJ, make sure to have version 15 and up.